# String join of distinct string

Tags: c#, performance, linq, strings

I have a class like this one:

```
class EmailClass 
{
    public string MailAdresse { get; set; }
    public string MailAdresseCC { get; set; }
}
```

Through a JSON deserialization I obtain a `List<EmailClass>` and two other strings `anotherMailAddress` and `justAnotherMailAddress`.

I need to join all those adresses in one big string (the separator is ";"). For this purpose I wrote this code:

```
// this one is populated in another section but it 
// is put there for the sake of knowing the  variable name
List<EmailClass> splittedList

List<string> listOfAdresses = new List<string>();
string joinedAdresses = String.Empty;

listOfAdresses.AddRange(splittedList.Select(x => x.MailAdresse));
listOfAdresses.AddRange(splittedList.Select(x => x.MailAdresseCC));
listOfAdresses.Add(anotherMailAddress);
listOfAdresses.Add(justAnotherMailAdresses);

joinedAdresses = String.Join(";", listOfAdresses.Distinct().ToArray());
```

Now, is there a more polished way to obtain this result?
How much will `Distinct()` affect the performance on medium result set (~100.000 adresses)? I've read that the complexity of the function should be O(n), is this true?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx) then it will only contain unique values, duplicates will be discarded when calling `Add` based upon the hashcode of the string. This should be far more efficient than calling `Distinct`.

```
List<EmailClass> splittedList

HashSet<string> listOfAdresses = new HashSet<string>();

// HashSet does not contain an AddRange method.
foreach (var emailClass in splittedList)
{
    listOfAdresses.Add(emailClass.MailAdresse);
    listOfAdresses.Add(emailClass.MailAdresseCC);
}

listOfAdresses.Add(anotherMailAddress);
listOfAdresses.Add(justAnotherMailAdresses);

string joinedAdresses = String.Join(";", listOfAdresses.ToArray());
```

--

Following the "feedback" from Almaz, here's a basic benchmark to show the performance difference (using unique values for each address):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<EmailClass> splittedList = Enumerable.Range(1, 100000).Select(i => new EmailClass
    {
        MailAdresse = i.ToString() + "@email.com",
        MailAdresseCC = i.ToString() + "cc@email.com"
    }).ToList();

    OriginalMethod(splittedList);
    HashSetMethod(splittedList);
    LinqMethod(splittedList);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void OriginalMethod(List<EmailClass> splittedList)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    List<string> listOfAdresses = new List<string>();

    listOfAdresses.AddRange(splittedList.Select(x => x.MailAdresse));
    listOfAdresses.AddRange(splittedList.Select(x => x.MailAdresseCC));
    listOfAdresses.Add("someone@email.com");
    listOfAdresses.Add("someone.else@email.com");
    var joinedAdresses = String.Join(";", listOfAdresses.Distinct().ToArray());
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("OriginalMethod");
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}

private static void HashSetMethod(List<EmailClass> splittedList)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    HashSet<string> listOfAdresses = new HashSet<string>();

    foreach (var emailClass in splittedList)
    {
        listOfAdresses.Add(emailClass.MailAdresse);
        listOfAdresses.Add(emailClass.MailAdresseCC);
    }

    listOfAdresses.Add("someone@email.com");
    listOfAdresses.Add("someone.else@email.com");

    string joinedAdresses = String.Join(";", listOfAdresses.ToArray());
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("HashSetMethod");
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}

private static void LinqMethod(List<EmailClass> splittedList)
{
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    var emails = splittedList.SelectMany(emailClass => new[] { emailClass.MailAdresse, emailClass.MailAdresseCC })
        .Concat(new[] { "someone@email.com", "someone.else@email.com" })
        .Distinct();

    var joinedAdresses = String.Join(";", emails);
    sw.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("LinqMethod");
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}
```

Results run in release mode without debugger attached:

```
OriginalMethod: 00:00:00.0789540
HashSetMethod:  00:00:00.0488568
LinqMethod:     00:00:00.0668056
```

Ramping up to 1,000,000 items

```
OriginalMethod: 00:00:00.8189667
HashSetMethod:  00:00:00.6891028
LinqMethod:     00:00:01.0157357
```

As you can see, the HashSet approach is substantially faster than the OP and significantly faster than the Linq approach.

Comment: Actually Distinct does almost the same, so your solution won't be faster then pure iteration over ".Distinct". See my answer.

Comment: Won't the hash set mess up the order of the strings?

Answer (score 3):

Solution can be optimized even further in terms of readability, with the same level of performance as "manually create a HashSet and populate it with items":

```
var emails = splittedList.SelectMany(emailClass => new[] { emailClass.MailAdresse, emailClass.MailAdresseCC})
    .Concat(new[] {anotherMailAddress, justAnotherMailAdress})
    .Distinct();
var joinedAdresses = String.Join(";", emails);
```

Comment: You can argue readability either way, fewer lines of code does not necessarily mean more readable. Also, this method will result in creating an array for every item in the source list which is completely unnecessary!

Comment: you can always do .Select(emailClass=>emailList.MailAdresse).Concat(splittedList.Select(emailClass=>emailList.MailAdresseCC)) to avoid creating arrays...

Comment: You could, but then you have to enumerate `splittedList` twice. Once to select the `EmailAddresse` and a second time to select the `EmailAddresseCC` which isn't an optimisation either as you're doing twice as much work! Linq isn't the answer to everything, just because you _can_ use it, doesn't mean you _should_ :)

Comment: I suggested another approach that (on my opinion) is more readable, expressive and compact. It declares what you want to do instead of how you want it to be done. Optimizing microseconds here is just a premature optimization, no-one will ever build a string containing a million of emails.